# most suitable way to insert more than 100 fields in a form using wpdb->insert()

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a WordPress form with **more than 100 fields**. I use the jQuery form plugin and send data in $_POST string using AJAX. all the column names in the table are the same as names in HTML fields.

```
jQuery('#save_form').button().click(function() {
    jQuery('#action').val('save_form');
    form = jQuery('#form');
    form.ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
```

In functions.php

```
function save_form(){
    if (!isset($_POST['_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_nonce'], 'form')) {
        wp_send_json_error([
            'message' => 'Error! refresh page and try again.'
        ]);
    }
```

> **// I can get all values in $_POST here...**

```
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert("TableName",
```

> **//Can I Pass Whole $_POST serialized string as an array to database or do I need to define all values one by one. There are more than 100 values in the form. If there is a simple way to pass all values is it possible to remove unwanted fields like _nonce & referee in $_POST string**

```
    ));



    wp_send_json_success([
        'message' => 'Success message',
    ]);
}

 add_action('wp_ajax_save_form', 'save_form');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this, it depends on what kind of data you have, the use for it, where it's coming from, etc.

You say the column names match the fields, so you have ~100 columns in a single database table?

The short answer to your question is:

> **Yes**, you can pass that array to the database with aligned columns.

### BUT

And I stress... ***you shouldn't***. You should be validating and perhaps even sanitizing the values based on their intended type. If you have a phone number, you should make sure that there are no funky symbols. If you have a website field, you should make sure it's a valid URL. (You're using `wpdb->insert`, so you shouldn't need to worry about SQL injection, but if you used an SQL query, you would want to parameterize it and prepare it).

Users are dingdongs, and somebody **will** put the wrong kind of data in the wrong field. Checking for that can add a little to the overhead of getting your platform ready, but it will save many headaches later.

Also, I can't help but wonder if your "100+ column" table could be set up better. It almost sounds like you'd be better off with a table more akin to WordPress' `post_meta` table, where it has:

```
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
```

You could use something similar like

```
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
| ID | entry_id | field |   value   |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 | email | a@123.com |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
|  2 |        1 | phone |  123-4567 |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
|  3 |        1 | name  |      John |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
|  4 |        2 | email | b@xyz.com |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
```

I don't have enough knowledge of your particular use-case to say that 100 columns is *wrong* (MySQL has a max column size of 4096, so…), but I'd carefully consider some DB Normalization first.